# 1000 * 256 *4 for loop takes a minute to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I'm trying to check the winning numbers of a simple gambling game. 
The user selects 4 cards of each symbol (diamond, heart etc') and by that he creates 256 combinations for that specific selection. 4*4*4*4 = 256 combinations.
I have an array of 1000 raffle results. Each result contains 4 winning cards and their numeric value.

I need to check how many winning cards each result contains.

My code looks something like this:

```
    for(int=0;i<results;i++) // [results count] = 1000
    {
         ...
         ...
        //take one results and check it against all combinations 
       for(int j=0;j<userCombinations;j++) // [userCombinations count] = 256
       {
        [self checkWins:[userCombinations objectAtIndex:j]]
       }
    }

-(void)checkWins:(NSMutableArray *)myArray
{
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
        //j=0 -> if heart numeric value equals to heart numeric result do something
        //j=1 -> if diamond numeric value equals to diamond numeric results do something

       }
}
```

There may be some typos in the code (wrote it from memory) but the basic idea is the same.
My question is this, the processes above takes:

- a few seconds on my i7 Mac Book Pro
- On an old Android the above, written in java, takes  6-9 seconds.
- On an iPhone 4 it takes a full minute to finish the process. < - **This is my problem**

Am I doing something wrong? Can you think of a better way to do the above?
Is there a way to speed things up?

Thanks

**Edit:**

The user selects these numbers

```
H  D  C   S
7  8  9  10
10 4  2  11
11 6  5  13
12 5  1  9
```

And gets 256 combinations.

```
First 6 combinations:      Current Raffle Result: 7 4 9 11
    H  D  C   S
    7  8  9  10    2 matches
    7  8  9  11    3 matches
    7  8  9  13    2 matches
    7  8  9  9     2 matches
    7  8  2  10    1 match
    7  8  2  11    1 Match
    etc'...        

              Total for Current Raffle Result 7 4 9 11:
                   3 matches - one time
                   2 matches - 3 Times
                   1 match - 2 times
```

I need to pass on all 256 combinations created and check them against every winning result. If one of the combinations contains a winning number I mark it and save it in an array so I can display it later.

Comment: I would probably first try putting the data in a standard C array, to check how much overhead NSArray adds to the algorithm.

Comment: Profile. We can't guess much from the partial code.

Comment: The only thing I would say is to find a way to not have a cubic algorithm here. For loop (linear) in another for loop (quadratic) in another for loop (cubic) is an ugly, inefficient way to code.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome if that's the only thing you'd say you are not very helpful. Saying something is ugly without suggesting an alternative is even uglier.

Comment: Is the user a winner if his 4 cards exactly match the raffle ticket?  Or do the 4 cards numeric values have to match the raffle ticket (ignoring the symbol)?

Comment: @MohammadS. The user wins if he got at least one card right. The symbol is never ignored.

Comment: The order is irelevent. The check I'm making is numeric value of heart against numeric value of hear, numeric value ofdiamond against numeric value of daimond etc'. I'll still have to run 256 times on each raffle result in order to find all winning combinations per One raffle result.

Comment: You can slightly improve your algorithm by adding an if statement around this looop: "for(int j=0;j<userCombinations;j++)".  Check if the 16 cards even exist in the currently selected raffle ticket.  This is a small improvement, but it may help a bit.

Comment: I'd get rid of the internal call, if reasonably possible, or convert it to a C call.  Objective-C call is not very fast.  And eliminate as much Objective-C stuff as possible in that inner loop.  Hard to say more without seeing your code and data structures.

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd do it is to represent each raffle result as an ordered c-string such as `c5d3h4s6` where `c5` = 5 of clubs comes before `s6` = 6 of spades.  Similarly order the user selection as a c-string, such as `c2c3c4c6d1d2d3d4h4h5h6h7s7s8s9s10`.

The purpose of this is so that you no longer need an inner loop permuting the user selection.
For each raffle, you can do a one pass scan through the selection to determine if `c5d3h4s6` has matched.  The results should be an order of magnitude faster.

Note we are not using Objective-C method dispatch here, as its not helpful performance-wise.

Comment: Nice solution! So using something like `rangeOfString` to find if the result matches for each of the 4 cards in the current result is acceptable ?

Comment: I would actually use strstr (C language).  Whilst the objective-C equivalent is good, I tend to use Obj-C for framework and business logic generally, and any "heavy lifting" code I do in C or C++ (.m or .mm files).

Comment: After thinking about your solution a bit I don't think it's possible. I Have to know in which combinations I have a winning number. See the edited question for a better understanding on what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider tackling this using maths (combinatorics or just counting...)

Consider 1 user guess - 16 cards - and 1 result - 4 cards. With at most 16 comparisons you can determine how many suits match.

If only 1 suit matches then there are 4^3 combinations where that one suit matches.

If 2 suits match then there are 4^2 combinations where those two match. But you also want to count the single matches. From above for *one* of those single matches there are 4^3 matches, but some of those overlap with the double matches so you need to subtract 4^2 of those 4^3 to get the number of just 1 matches. Now as you started with 2 matches you have *two* single matches to consider...

Continue with 3 & 4 suits matching - it's just maths, no loops required at this level...

But you can do even better; the result is *only* based on the number of matches (0-4), which means you can pre-calculate the results, and if get lost in the maths just enumerate the possibilities and count. That gets you down to 1000 (number of solutions) x (max 16 comparisons + lookup).

HTH.